# How to open file in multi thread(over 10 threads) using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I'm sorry, I'm not good at English.

I'm trying to load image files in multi thread using OpenMP.
But, when I set number of threads(num_threads()) to 10 and execute the program, the program shows "Segmentation fault".
If I set number of threads to 9, it will work. My server(centos7.6) has 32 maximum available threads and 350GB memories. So, I think it is possible to load 10 image files at the same time.
I don't know why this happens. Is there any limits to open files in multi thread?

This is my sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char target_file[256] = { 0 };

    omp_set_nested(1);

    printf("maximum available threads : %d\n", omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel for private(target_file) num_thread(10)
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        sprintf(target_file, "./data/%d.bmp", i);
        printf("[%d]:target file : %s\n", omp_get_thread_num(), target_file);

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(target_file, "rw");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("failed to open file : %s\n", target_file);
        }

        printf("[%d]: %d.bmp file opened.\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

This is output when I set num_threads() to 10.

```
maximum available threads : 32
[8]:target file : ./data/81.bmp
[5]:target file : ./data/51.bmp
[0]:target file : ./data/1.bmp
[6]:target file : ./data/61.bmp
[0]: 1.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/2.bmp
[6]: 61.bmp file opened.
[9]:target file : ./data/91.bmp
[3]:target file : ./data/31.bmp
[4]:target file : ./data/41.bmp
[8]: 81.bmp file opened.
[4]: 41.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/42.bmp
[4]: 42.bmp file opened.
[0]: 2.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/3.bmp
[0]: 3.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/4.bmp
[0]: 4.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/5.bmp
[0]: 5.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/6.bmp
[0]: 6.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/7.bmp
[0]: 7.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/8.bmp
[0]: 8.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/9.bmp
[0]: 9.bmp file opened.
[9]: 91.bmp file opened.
[8]:target file : ./data/82.bmp
[7]:target file : ./data/71.bmp
[5]: 51.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/43.bmp
[4]: 43.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/44.bmp
[4]: 44.bmp file opened.
[0]:target file : ./data/10.bmp
[0]: 10.bmp file opened.
[8]: 82.bmp file opened.
[5]:target file : ./data/52.bmp
[7]: 71.bmp file opened.
[1]:target file : ./data/11.bmp
[6]:target file : ./data/62.bmp
[3]: 31.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/45.bmp
[4]: 45.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/46.bmp
[4]: 46.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/47.bmp
[4]: 47.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/48.bmp
[4]: 48.bmp file opened.
[4]:target file : ./data/49.bmp
[8]:target file : ./data/83.bmp
[5]: 52.bmp file opened.
[7]:target file : ./data/72.bmp
[1]: 11.bmp file opened.
[6]: 62.bmp file opened.
[3]:target file : ./data/32.bmp
[2]:target file : ./data/21.bmp
[4]: 49.bmp file opened.
[8]: 83.bmp file opened.
[5]:target file : ./data/53.bmp
[7]: 72.bmp file opened.
[7]:target file : ./data/73.bmp
[7]: 73.bmp file opened.
[7]:target file : ./data/74.bmp
[7]: 74.bmp file opened.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Maybe inconsequential here, but you misspelled `#pragma`

Comment: It my mistake when typing, sorry

Comment: Consider the scope of "target_file"...

Comment: *So, I think it is possible to load 10 image files at the same time.*  If your processing is I/O bound, that won't make processing faster.  If the files are all on the same disk, it's actually likely to make your processing slower depending on how you access the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file are closed even when they are not opened causing a crash.
Moreover `num_threads(10)` should be used instead of `num_thread`.
Finally, moving `target_file` into the section is more efficient and safe.
Here is the resulting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    omp_set_nested(1);

    printf("maximum available threads : %d\n", omp_get_max_threads());

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(10)
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        char target_file[256] = { 0 };

        sprintf(target_file, "./data/%d.bmp", i);
        printf("[%d]:target file : %s\n", omp_get_thread_num(), target_file);

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(target_file, "rw");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("failed to open file : %s\n", target_file);
            continue;
        }

        printf("[%d]: %d.bmp file opened.\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

PS: note that you can use the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to tune the number of threads used at runtime rather than fixing it manually in the code (this is more flexible and portable).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I fix it but still doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work: you still have a segmentation fault? Do you execute this exact code without any modifications? What compiler do you use and which version? What is your OS? And what is your processor?

Comment: Sorry for late the reply. Yes, I executed without any modifications. Compiler is "gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)". OS is "CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810".
Processor is "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz"

Comment: Your version of GCC is quite old. I remember old versions to have some OpenMP bugs now mostly fixed in the latest versions although I never saw a compiler bug on such a simple code. Can you try with a recent GCC (eg. GCC 9 or 10)? Note there are tools such like [Spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do it easily.

Comment: I upgraded GCC to version 9 and try it. It works successfully! Thank you for your advice.